# integer primary key for replication

Tags: database, replication, firebird

I am weighing my options for integer primary keys that can be used in multi master replication. (I'm pretty much sold on using integer keys instead of GUIDs)

The best I can come up with is having the most significant data first and having the server number last:
eg. invoice 1 on server 1 = 101
invoice 1 on server 2 = 102
where the non serverno part (invoiceno) comes from a db number generator

algorithmically: gen_id(INVOICENO_GEN, 1) * 100 + serverno
and you can get the server number by both looking at the value and mathematically.

Which leaves room for 99 servers while still being short and readable and won't collide. Using that scheme and normal integer size column would make the max rows (21 474 836) or if bigint is used many billions.

for instance the invoice table keys would look like this:

```
Server 1    
101
201
301
401

Server 2    
102
202
302
402
```

**So my question is: any critiques or flaws I have overlooked?**

The database is Firebird.

Answer (score 2):

How about just creating a composite primary key?

Define a "ServerID" to set on each server, e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. as an INT. Then have the "InvoiceID" as an INT on your Invoice table.

Create the primary key to be (ServerID,InvoiceID).

That way, you have room for way more than 99 servers, and you don't have to manipulate / calculate any ID's or anything like that.

Of course, any table referencing your Invoice table now needs to use (ServerID,InvoiceID) as the foreign key, too - but I guess having the ServerID everywhere in your tables isn't going to be a problem if you need to replicate those tables, too.

Marc

Comment: I wouldn't want to introduce a composite key for this. For one, composite keys are a PITA to deal with, and it doesn't look like he's actually interested in relating this data based upon the additional information.

Comment: Most of our code and the libraries we use are optimized for use with a single primary key. So a composite primary key is the "right" answer from a database viewpoint but not nice from a development perspective.

Comment: just to clarify we will have a serverno column as well for querying purposes. We don't have an invoiceno (without the serverno) column because that is what we want printed on invoices, lookups, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In general, *don't use numeric types for anything that isn't a number*. Treating the digits with special significance makes your numbers no longer strictly numeric. A string is usually more suited to scenarios like this where you want to add some environment-specific data (usually for replication).

Comment: Well we don't actually intent to use the embeded digits eg. in queries. It's just a way to separate multiple incrementing values similar to changing the step or start of the generator.

Comment: but you make a good point. Will have to do some benchmarks to see if an integer primary key is really a large gain or not.